# Iterate through folder hierarchy

Tags: r

I have a folder (my_files) that has about 1000 folders inside of them. Each of these 1000 folders has 6 csv files inside of them. I would like to get 1000 csv files by aggregating these 6 csv's per directory.

I have the following code:

```
files<-list.files("/Users/me/Desktop/my_files")
for (i in files)
{
         //open each directory in "files"
        //aggregate all csvs in the directory into one
       //name of the aggregated csvs should be the name of the folder they were inside of
}
```

I am trying to use something like:

```
for (i in files)
{
    files2<-list.files("/Users/me/Desktop/my_files/"i)
}
```

To list the files within the directories in my_files, but obviously that is wrong syntax.

Comment: If all you want is to get the resulting CSV files then Bash may be a better tool than R for this.

Comment: I would like to aggregate all the csv files within different directories into one. E.g. the folder my_files/xxx has 6 csv files, I would like to end up with one xxx.csv file that is all of the 6 csv files put together. I can do this one by one in R, but that would be too much for so many directories. I don't know much about bash, what do you think I should google to do something like this in bash? Are there any specific commands that would be helpful?

Comment: BASH is the standard Linux command shell.

Comment: Wait.  Are you trying to just merge the CSV data in R, or do you need these files for something else?

Comment: @demt Depending on how your files are organised it could be as simple as `for folder in my_files/*; do cat "$folder"/*.csv > "$folder.csv"; done` in Bash.

Comment: oh, I know about bash, I just didn't know which bash commands I should look into and whether this is possible to do with bash at all.

Comment: 'Tis easy in BASH, as Konrad demonstrates, provided you are just trying to merge lines of text from multiple files into one.  This doesn't help you get it into R, but if this is a just an aggregation task, BASH is far more suitable of a tool.

Comment: Awesome, I will try this out now, I can just get them into R later, that should be easy!

Comment: Can't get it to work unfortunately, since I think it reads "$folder"/*.csv simply as my_files/*.csv and says that there is no such directory.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a folder called `my_files` and populated it with `folder1`, `folder2` and `folder3`. Each folder holds a file1.txt with a hidden message. Let's see what those messages read. The anonymous function could be adapted to read in all your files and combining them. I will leave you to the task.

```
# I've created a folder "my_files" that is...
setwd("q:/my_files")

# populated by three subfolders
thousand.folders <- list.dirs(full.names = TRUE)

result <- sapply(thousand.folders[-1], function(x) {
  file <- list.files(x, full.names = TRUE)  
  message(readLines(file))
})

file1 in folder1
file1 in folder2
file1 in folder3
```

Comment: I am still not sure how to make this work... my result looks like this: $`./9980072`
[1] "./9980072/data_B_2012_08.csv" "./9980072/data_B_2012_09.csv" "./9980072/data_B_2012_10.csv" "./9980072/data_B_2012_11.csv"
[5] "./9980072/data_B_2012_12.csv" "./9980072/data_B_2013_01.csv"  So, I have the directory within my_files, which is /9980072, and within that I have the csv files, and I would like to merge those csv files and name these merged csv files the name of the directory, in this case 9980072.csv